# Tabulate test scores

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on vba code and would like to do the following:

Read:

```
  A      B
1 John   100
2 Jill   90 
3 John   95
4 Amy    82
```

Change to (in alphabetical order):

```
  A    B   C
1 Amy  82
2 Jill 90
3 John 100 95
```

Ultimately i need it to display the student's name and all scores next to the name.

So far i have this:

```
Sub Combine()

Dim J As Integer
Dim wrk As Workbook 'Workbook object - Always good to work with object variables
Dim wrk1 As Worksheet
Dim r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, ra, rb, rc, rd, re, rf, rg As Range
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Set r1 = Range("D:D")
Set r2 = Range("B:B")
Set r3 = Range("E:E")
Set r4 = Range("C:C")
Set r5 = Range("F:F")
Set r6 = Range("H:H")
Set r7 = Range("AX:AX")
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Set ra = Range("D:D")
Set rb = Range("B:B")
Set rc = Range("E:E")
Set rd = Range("C:C")
Set re = Range("F:F")
Set rf = Range("H:H")
Set rg = Range("AX:AX")

Set wrk = Workbooks.Add

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Activate

 r1.Copy Range("A1")
 r2.Copy Range("B1")
 r3.Copy Range("C1")
 r4.Copy Range("D1")
 r5.Copy Range("E1")
 r6.Copy Range("F1")
 r7.Copy Range("G1")

 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Activate

 ra.Copy Range("A1")
 rb.Copy Range("B1")
 rc.Copy Range("C1")
 rd.Copy Range("D1")
 re.Copy Range("E1")
 rf.Copy Range("F1")
 rg.Copy Range("G1")

On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A2").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(J).Activate
Range("A3").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)

Sheets(1).Select

Range("A1:AY100").Sort _
Key1:=Range("C1"), Key2:=Range("B1"), Header:=xlYes



Next



End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a question you would like to ask?

Comment: Yes. How can i get it to display from 
       A      B 
1 John 100 
2 Jill       90 
3 John  95 
4 Amy    82 

Change to (in alphabetical order): 
       A      B     C 
1 Amy   82 
2 Jill      90 
3 John 100   95

Comment: What problem are you experiencing with the code you wrote? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Have you even tried just recording a macro while sorting your column A from A-Z?

Comment: I have very limited vba knowledge. So far i only got the data to collate. I dont even know how to get it to find or display the way i want it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a pivot table for your case. It's easy to create, updates easily and good to maintain. However, here is some piece of code:

```
Sub pivotDataInColumns()
    Dim sourceSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim destinationSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim sourceRow As Long
    Dim destinationRow As Long
    Dim matchRow As Long
    Dim searchColumn As Excel.Range
    Dim nameToFind As String
    Dim lastColumn As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook
        'Change Worksheet name to suit:
        Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set destinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    End With
    Set searchColumn = destinationSheet.Columns("A")

    For sourceRow = 1 To getLastRow(sourceSheet.Columns("A"))
        nameToFind = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceRow, "A").Value

        destinationRow = getMatchRow(nameToFind, searchColumn)
        If destinationRow = 0 Then
            destinationRow = getLastRow(destinationSheet.Columns("A")) + 1
            destinationSheet.Cells(destinationRow, "A").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceRow, "A").Value
        End If

        lastColumn = getLastColumn(destinationSheet.Rows(destinationRow)) + 1
        destinationSheet.Cells(destinationRow, lastColumn).Value2 = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceRow, "B").Value2
    Next sourceRow

    'Remove row 1 garbage and sort:
    With destinationSheet
        .Rows(1).Delete
        .UsedRange.Sort Key1:=.Range("A1"), _
                        Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Header:=xlNo
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Data processed successfully.", vbInformation
End Sub

Private Function getMatchRow(searchValue As Variant, _
                             searchArray As Variant) As Long
  'This function returns 0 if searchValue is not on searchArray.

  Dim element As Long

  On Error Resume Next
  element = WorksheetFunction.Match(CDbl(searchValue), searchArray, 0)
  If element = 0 Then element = WorksheetFunction.Match(CStr(searchValue), searchArray, 0)

  getMatchRow = element
End Function

Private Function getLastRow(sourceRange As Excel.Range) As Long
    Dim parentSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set parentSheet = sourceRange.Parent
    With parentSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, sourceRange.column).End(xlUp).row
    End With

    getLastRow = lastRow
End Function

Private Function getLastColumn(sourceRange As Excel.Range) As Long
    Dim parentSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lastColumn As Long

    Set parentSheet = sourceRange.Parent
    With parentSheet
        lastColumn = .Cells(sourceRange.row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
    End With

    getLastColumn = lastColumn
End Function
```